# Navigate to first available folder in windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

Two cases:

1. There is only one folder inside the working directory.
2. There are a bunch of folders inside the working directory and need to navigate inside the first available folder sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 17):

1. Type `cd` and add a <kbd>Space</kbd> (don't press <kbd>Enter</kbd> yet).
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once, that will add the first available directory
3. If you want the next one, keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>

---

<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows command line works in a different way than Linux's. In Linux, it will refuse to complete the word if there are several possibilities, and it will list them if you insist. In Windows, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> several times will circle through the possibilities, and it might even overwrite what you already typed.

Comment: Nice! I never noticed that `cmd` was smart enough to skip non-directories when Tabbing through entries.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a for loop to get the folder.
On a drive with inherent alphabetical sorting (ntfs-format) you can use the simpler `For /D` otherwise you'll need a `For /f` parsing the ouput of a dir command.

```
@Echo off
Set "FirstDir="
For /d %%D in ("X:\Path\to\workdir\*") do If not defined FirstDir Set "FirstDir=%%D"
PushD "%FirstDir%"
Echo current dir = %CD%
Pause
PopD
```

For the more reliable version replace the above for with this one:

```
For /F "delims=" %%D in ('Dir /B/AD/ON "X:\Path\to\workdir\*"') do If not defined FirstDir Set "FirstDir=%%D"
```

Resetting the var `FirstDir` and in the loop checking for existence ensures you get only the first directory.

Comment: forfiles is a much easier approach if you want to go this way though.